# C# Console application does work when started from Visual studio, after publishing it only runs for 3 cycles is this normal behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I made a C# console application (.NET CORE 5.0) to check every minute for changes in a MySQL database and send e-mails with the changes.

If I run this application directly from visual studio 2019, it works fine without any problems.

If I run it after I publish it, it only does 3 cycles and the console window stays open. No errors or anything else.

This first screenshot is from running via Visual Studio 2019
[image: Screenshot running from visual studio]

This is screenshot is from running directly from desktop after publish
[image: Screenshot running after publish]

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            
            TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(DoStuff);

            Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000);

            for (; ; )
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }
```

```
        static public void DoStuff(Object stateInfo)
        {
            DataTable DtblEmployee = DatabaseClass.GetEmployeeList();

            foreach (DataRow row in DtblEmployee.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    string Str = RandomStringGenerator.GetRandomAlphanumericString(8);
                    DatabaseClass.EmployeeUpdate(item.ToString(), Str);
                    EmailClass.SendEmail(item.ToString(), Str);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Last check was @  {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"));
            Console.WriteLine("{0} e-mail(s) were send.", DtblEmployee.Rows.Count);

        }
```

The program is supposed to run forever.

Would love to hear from you guys, if more information is needed please ask.

EDIT: Added extra code to show Database

```
public static void EmployeeUpdate(string Emailadress, string Password)
        {
            string connectionstring;
            connectionstring = "server=1.1.1.1;user id=User;password=Pass;port=3306;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=Test";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Users SET Password=@param_val_1, GeneratePassword=@param_val_3 where Username=@param_val_2", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_val_1", Password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_val_2", Emailadress);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_val_3", 0);

                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sometime, the console window stop refresh. Try press enter or move the windows.

Comment: Just FYI "to check every minute" - your timer is set to 1000, which is every second (1000 ms = 1 sec)

Comment: @Vernou That was my first thought and didn't work.

Comment: @PeterB sorry changed it to 1 second for faster testing, my bad for not mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 100% agree with JonSkeet about the reason.

It's the GC that cleans up the stateTimer variable. Right after this line, this variable becomes unused and the compiler is free to get rid of it from the stack, and then GC is free to get rid of the timer.

When you are running your application in different environments, the GC may be using different set rules. Debugging session, console app, IIS Application, module for SqlServer, etc - they all have different rules as for when and how aggressively run the GC. Under debugging session, it also MAY clean up this variable, but it also MAY do it hours or days later, maybe to give you more time to inspect things? Under free-running console app, it simply occurred sooner.

GC also has its hard rules that has to abide them always: if the variable is used, it cannot be purged.

JonSkeet suggested pinning the stateTimer, I disagree. It's a last-resort option.

Much better, just use USING directive, as the Timer is a IDisposable:

```
        TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(DoStuff);

        using(Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000))
            for (; ; )
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
```

The variable is still unused, you can even get rid of it and write

```
        using(new Timer(callback, null, 0, 1000))
```

but even now, the `using()` statement will remember that Timer object and prevent GC from cleaning it up too soon. (It has to remember that object to be able to call Dispose() when the loop ends..)

Answer (score 3):

I *strongly* expect that the problem is that your `Timer` is being garbage collected and finalized, and that's stopping the callback from being executed.

When you run your code from Visual Studio *in the debugger*, the JIT is less aggressive about garbage collection, which is why it's working in that scenario.

The smallest change to fix that would be to add this line at the end of your `Main` method:

```cs
GC.KeepAlive(stateTimer);
```

Alternatively, as per [quetzalcoatl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64589444/22656), you could use a `using` statement for the timer. Either option will have the desired effect of keeping the timer alive for the duration of the method.

An alternative I think you should explore would be to not use a timer at all, instead just loop within the `Main` method and call your `DoStuff` method directly. You'd still call `Sleep` within that loop, which would handle the timing aspect. Obviously that will affect the precise timing of how the code runs, but it's likely to end up being simpler to understand and simpler to debug.

Additionally, I'd suggest being a lot more intentional about your exception handling. Work out whether you want the code to stop looping if any one iteration throws an exception, and make that explicit in the code.

Comment: According to this tip: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netcore-3.1 we have 5 more or less standard "Timer" classes, and only 1 of them uses a "TimerCallback" delegate: the `System.Threading.Timer`. Other 4 use: ElapsedEventHandler, EventHandler, EventHandler<EventArgs> and EventHandler again. I doubt the OP used any extra library for timers, so it's mostly clear it's System.Threading.Timer.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Ah yes, thanks for the extra detective work. It would have been simpler if the OP had just provided a [mcve] of course.

Comment: btw. `GC.KeepAlive(stateTimer);` is a bit of overkill. See my answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your explanation, everything is more clear now, as for the minimal reprodicible example. This is the only code there really is. The application is really basic I only have a main and a DoStuff. And then just an update/select database method and a random string generator.

Not sure on how to give you more information for a minimal reproducible example.
The 'main' and the 'dostuff' were enough to recreate this problem for me.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: I don't think I'd regard it as "overkill" but I agree that a using statement is fine. I think avoiding a timer would be better in the first place though.

Comment: @JeffreyLionelvanHoudt: "This is the only code there really is." Then it wouldn't compile, because you haven't provided a class declaration or any using directives. We shouldn't have to *guess* or do detective work to figure out which of the 5 different `Timer` classes you meant. A reproducible example should be able to compile and run *without* me having to add anything else.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for informing me, do you mean I should have added these lines.

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;

Just let me know if this is what you meant. Thank you for your time.

Edit: When checking my question these were the only lines I didn't post so it has be this.

Comment: @JeffreyLionelvanHoudt: Yes, and the class declaration. Basically, we want to be able to copy the code into a new file, compile it and run. Note that to make it *minimal* you could have removed all the database access from `DoStuff` as well - that would still have demonstrated the problem, and eliminated the database access from the context.